# Less is compiled and bundled into one big

Tags: css, less

There are multiple .less files that are compiled and then served to the page as a big .css file.

I would like in the browser to ( after the entire page loads ), only show css that is being used on the page.

Furthemore I would like that a sourcemap of less be shown so i may debug the less files in the browser, only the .less files or better yet, highlight the .less lines that are being used on that specific page.

Here is a possible scenario I am thinking.

We have https://github.com/giakki/uncss that removes unused css from a html page.

Good.

Now after the css is removed, I want the remaning css to somehow be mapped back to .less.

Then once i debug, I will see only the used .less on that page.

Thanks.

Comment: hummm gulp or grunt tasks?

Comment: Can't use them can't modify build pipeline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There are multiple .less files that are compiled and then served to
>   the page as a big .css file.
>
> I would like in the browser to ( after the entire page loads ), only
>   show css that is being used on the page.

This is intentional. Since you are using a CSS preprocessor, what actually gets served to end users is the CSS code compiled from Less--not the Less code itself. The decision of what Less code gets compiled into what CSS is all server-side. If you are seeing all these .less files being compiled into one, big .css file, then this is just how the server is serving it to you (or how you are serving it to yourself if you are playing around in a development environment).

> Furthemore I would like that a sourcemap of less be shown so i may debug the less files in the browser, only the .less files or better yet, highlight the .less lines that are being used on that specific page.

You can have this set up almost exactly how you want. Live editing of Less can be set up in both Firefox and Chrome. For more information on how to set this up for Firefox and Google Chrome, see these links:

- [Live Editing Sass and Less in the Firefox Developer Tools](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/02/live-editing-sass-and-less-in-the-firefox-developer-tools/)
- [Map Preprocessed Code to Source Code](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/source-maps)

I know for Firefox in partcular that you have to manually enable source maps. Once this is done, Firefox will also show you the less styles corresponding to individual HTML elements (that you inspect) in the [CSS pane](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/UI_Tour#Rules_view). So, this will at least help you see what less rules apply to individual elements--if not the entire page.

Chrome 59 added a CSS and JS coverage tool that should help you find out what styles are being used and what styles are not being used. You might be able to get similar functionality out of Firefox with addons. This would likely only apply to plain CSS and JS, however--not Less. See:

- [What's New In DevTools (Chrome 59) - CSS and JS Coverage](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/devtools-release-notes#coverage)

### Keywords you might want to search for are "CSS coverage", "Live editing of Less in-browser", etc.

EDIT: I'm adding this on after you had editing your question. I would check out:

- https://github.com/purifycss/purifycss

This would clean up the CSS. Then as mentioned in this issue, you could compare sourcemaps for the dirty versus purified CSS to get your 'clean' Less code:

- https://github.com/purifycss/purifycss/issues/74